# RewriteRule: different result depending on the PC

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I have this line in my .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^test.mypage.eu [NC] 
RewriteRule (.*)$ https://test.mypage.eu [R=301,L]
```

When i do the request, it's doing the redirection OK from one PC but from another one no. Any idea what can be the problem?

Regards

Javi

Comment: You mean from one client PC it works, but from a different client PC is not?  Turn on the rewrite log, and post the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that you rewrite module is activated on the second box, some distro ship with that module disabled by default.
On debian-based distros you can use `a2enmod rewrite` to enable it, don't forget to restart apache after that.

Comment: Ubuntu also has .htaccess files turned off and you need to add `AllowOverride All` to you apache2.conf file.